# Expected end of line, etc. but found “script”

Tags: macos, applescript, iterm2

I wrote a very basic apple script that opens `iTerm` and goes to a file:

```
tell application "iTerm"
    activate
    do script "cd ~" in tab 1
end tell
```

If I try to run this however, I get a `Syntax Error`:

```
Expected end of line, etc. but found “script”.
```

Any idea why this is the case?

Is there some incorrect syntax in this script?

Comment: This works for Terminal app. For iTerm, the syntax is different and your answer works fine

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it turns out that the syntax was incorrect.

This works:

```
tell application "iTerm"
    create window with default profile
    tell current session of current window
        write text "cd ~"
    end tell
end tell
```